# converts to double array after declaring req.body

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to start a foreach for a variable that can be a single id one or an array of multiple ids. First I try to verify if its an array or not and if not I declare it as an array of only 1 item.

```
router.post("/providerQuote", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.idQuote);
  var idQuote = [];
  if(req.body.idQuote.isArray)
  {
    idQuote = Object.values(req.body.idQuote);
  }else{
    idQuote = [req.body.idQuote];
  }
  console.log(idQuote);
  idQuote.forEach(function (quote){
    console.log(quote);
    });
```

This is the console log:

```
Server Started...
[ '5bfed54c9b0d061574d874c0', '5bfed54c9b0d061574d874bf' ]
[ [ '5bfed54c9b0d061574d874c0', '5bfed54c9b0d061574d874bf' ] ]
[ '5bfed54c9b0d061574d874c0', '5bfed54c9b0d061574d874bf' ]
```

The problem here is that somehow it is inserting the req.body into another array.

Comment: Do you mean to use `if (Array.isArray(req.body.idQuote))`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you’re saying, the idQuote value in the response may be a string or it may be an array of strings, and you’re trying to just always have a single array of strings. If I’m correct in that, I would just change your code to the following:

```
router.post("/providerQuote", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.idQuote);
  var idQuote = req.body.idQuote;
  if(!Array.isArray(idQuote)) {
    idQuote = [idQuote];
  }

  console.log(idQuote);
  idQuote.forEach(function (quote){
    console.log(quote);
    });
```

This will simply wrap your idQuote in an array if it is not currently an array.

By defaulting the idQuote variable to req.body.idQuote, I’m doing a few things:

1. I’m simplifying the code. If idQuote is actually an array, there’s nothing more to do! We’re good to go.
2. We aren’t retyping req.body.idQuote multiple times, when we need to use it either way. There’s an acronym in programming called being DRY which means “Do not Repeat Yourself”. If you find yourself doing the same thing multiple times, there’s likely a way to simplify your code.
3. I’m avoiding doing excessive processing. Your original code created an empty array and then filled it with the values of a different array. No offense at all to you, but that’s quite a bit of unnecessary work (create a whole new array object in memory and then loop through one array copying its values into a new one) when you have a perfectly good array right there that looks exactly the way you want.
   Excessive processing costs money: on a server it means you’ll need a bigger server sooner because you can’t handle quite as much as you could have if things were more efficient. On the client excessive processing means battery drain and at times a choppy and laggy user experience. It’s good to look for little things that could be improved because while one tiny thing doesn’t really matter, they can add up quickly if there’s a lot of them in your code, especially if they’re in a long loop. It’s little tricks that you learn along the way that actually help quite a bit.

Also know that isArray is a method on Array. Since you had no parenthesis, you’re basically checking whether or not the current object has an isArray method, and I’m pretty confident that none of it did (because it’s a static method on the Array class), which then pushed you down into the else where you wrapped it in an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this

```
if ( Array.isArray(req.body.idQuote) ) {
  // Perform your operations here
} else {
  idQuote.push(req.body.idQuote)
}
```